# how to sum the item in a php loop from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $query2 = QModel::query("SELECT * FROM transaction");
    while($get2 = QModel::g($query2)) {
        $totalprice = $get2['price'];
        echo array_sum($totalprice);
    }
?>
```

I get php error:

Message: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

please help thanks

Comment: what you have used image instead of code here ?

Comment: I cant used code, theres an error.

Comment: i am just asking to write code here instead of image

Comment: I just answer you sir :D

Comment: my fault I echo inside while(){} :D thanks guys!

Comment: @JoelEnanodJr I saw that and I've posted it in my answer.Also $total price is not an array in the posted example...if I'm right..

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this :

```
$totalprice += $get1['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($get2==Qmodel::query("select * from transaction"))
{
    $totalprice[]=$get2['price'];
}
echo array_sum($totalprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(..)
{
    $totalpirce += $get2['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$query2 = QModel::query('SELECT FROM transaction');
while($get2 = QModel::q($query2)){
  $sum += $get2['price'];
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `SELECT transaction.*, SUM(price) as total_price FROM transaction`?

Answer (score 0):

`$totalprice=$get2['price];`=>incorrect way of define array
    `$totalprice[]=$get2['price];`=>correct way of define array

```
$totalprice=array();
$query="";
while(condition){
      $totalprice[]=$get2['price];
}echo array_sum($totalprice);
```

Comment: okey, i think $totalprice=$get2['price];=>incorrect way of define array $totalprice[]=$get2['price];=>correct way of define array must be cosider